# Shell passing keystore path parameter in jarsigner

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jarsigner

I have this

```
KEY_STORE_PATH=/home/userr/mykeystore

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "$KEY_STORE_PATH" bin/PName-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

and it doesn't work, after this command the apk file it is not signed...

But when I do this it works just fine

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore /home/userr/mykeystore bin/PName-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

EDIT:
actually what I do is the following

```
echo ` echo "pass" | jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "$KEY_STORE_PATH" bin/PName-release-unsigned.apk alias_name`
```

no I can guess what is the problem but , is there solution for this kind of situation ?

EDIT 2

I did short test

In shell

```
 #  asd=123
 #  echo `echo $asd`
 #  123
```

it print 123 correctly so I think something else is the problem

Comment: Are you calling both lines from the same shell session or script?

Comment: @choroba nice question I think I realize the problem, see my edit

Comment: Try the following: `echo \`echo jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "$KEY_STORE_PATH" bin/PName-release-unsigned.apk alias_name\``. The point is to see whether the variable is substituted (as it should). Also, please check for a potential typo. Finally, what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you call jarsigner from inside of a subshell / another script, you should export your environmental variable:

```
export KEY_STORE_PATH=/home/userr/mykeystore
```